# how can i show audio recorded file from phone memory to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

i have developed call recording application. it record the audio file and save it into the Phone memory (File Manager). know how can i show this recorded file in my application using ListView.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kick off example:

```
String[] files = new File("path/to/dir/with_your_files").list();
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
listView.setAdapter(a);
```

Comment: if i switch off my mobile and then switch on then all your data will be lost dude

Comment: static and non static member of class is remain until or unless it present in stack only

Comment: "Phone memory (File Manager)" I am sure that it means ROM, not RAM.

Comment: dude all variable manage by heap memory if u store String[] then when u swtich off ur mob then it will be null how u trace or save all file info which u hold earlier

Comment: Omg man, are you kidding me? If he saved all recorded files in directory and want to show it in ListView, he will reread content of that directory everytime and show to-date information.

Comment: yes @Divers it is ROM. and Bhanu Sharma i restarted my Mobile, my data isn't lost. it remains same as before restarting the mobile.

Comment: dude if u fetch all record all time then no need for database i mean to say y we fetch every time just when u record then only manage database in this all time u have to fetch all data in String[]  then u will show if u manage database then no need to fetch sdcard or internal memory to fetch that data

Answer (score 1):

Manage all your app recorded file information like. file NAME,File path,time date (optional)  in one database of application whenever try to show in list just fetch that data extract file path and show in list view. All info of file like file size,type u able to get from file only with native file method :)